# Código javascript não funciona no chrome

Tags: javascript

Estou começando com javascript e fiz o seguinte código abaixo, só que ele não está funcionando no google chrome, por que?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="teste" id="teste"/>
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</html>
```

test.js

```
var teste = document.getElementById("teste");

teste.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert(1);
});
```

Já testei ele no Firefox e no site JS Bin e ele funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Inclua no seu script: `<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js" defer></script>`

Comment: Inclua também sua tag `script` antes do fechamento da tag `body` e não depois. Alias, qual versão do chrome você esta usando? Minha versão `58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)` está funcionando, não sei se isso tem influência, mas o chrome corrigiu a estrutura, colocando automaticamente a tag `script` antes do fechamento do  `body`.

Comment: A mais nova, esse "defer" serve pra que? mas eu acho que sei o que aconteceu, o chrome estava salvando em cache o código antigo e não o novo.

Comment: `defer` garante que o script seja carregado somente depois do carregamento do html, para versões muito antigas de navegadores, não funciona

Comment: Dica: utilize sempre o modo anonimo para fazer seus testes, e não ha problema em usar o script entre as tags `<body>`

Comment: Certo, obrigado, existe algum "modo desenvolvedor" para testar scripts sem cache?

Comment: [Modo anonimo](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?source=gsearch&hl=pt-BR)

Comment: Testei no chrome e funcionou sem problemas - i.e. não consigo reproduzir o problema.

Comment: @HenriqueOliveira, resolveu seu problema? Era cache mesmo?

Answer (score 4):

O problema pode ser o local da tag `script`, não é correto colocá-la depois do fechamento de `body`.

Se você pretende que o script seja carregado depois do corpo do HTML, coloque a tag **antes do fechamento** de `body`.

Isso pode variar de um *browser* pra outro e de versão pra versão, eu testei no Chrome e Firefox (ambos no Windows) e em nenhum dos dois o alert foi mostrado. De qualquer forma o melhor é **sempre** seguir [as recomendações da W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1). Veja um trecho retirado da seção sobre a tag script.

> This element may appear any number of times in the HEAD or BODY of an HTML document.

Em tradução livre

> Este elemento pode aparecer quantas vezes for necessário no HEAD ou BODY de um documento HTML.

Logo, seu código HTML deveria ser:

```
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="teste" id="teste"/>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

Se você quiser, pode testar no [*validator* da W3C](https://validator.w3.org) que verá um erro sendo acusado.

Answer (score -3):

Tente adicionar o seguinte código:

```
window.document.onload = function(e){ 
  var teste = document.getElementById("teste");
  teste.addEventListener('click', function(){
     alert(1);
  });
}
```

Assim será adicionado o evento ao botão após a página estiver pronta / DOM acessivel